# Posting to Facebook page without user interaction

Tags: facebook

I have a requirement where I need to post updates to a client page.  This update is triggered by an action from a web application,  the update to the page is to be done on the server with no user interaction and no web browser and should still be able to post if the admin/user of the page is logged out.

I have read many posts and pages of documentation and all the answers seem to point to 'no you cannot do this' but don't actually commit to saying no.  Can anybody tell me if this is really possible ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This **is** possible but you'll need *some user interaction* at some point to get the `manage_pages` permission from the user. Once you have that permission, you'll be able to query the `/me/accounts` endpoint and extract the page access token.

You use that page access token to post to the page and you won't need any user interaction once you have a valid page access token. Make sure to put in place some error handling to handle cases where the access token becomes invalid.

Reference -

- [Facebook permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
- [Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)

Comment: The page has already granted access to the manage_pages permission to the app, I can't get the page access token automatically without getting a user access token in order to use the accounts endpoint.

I can get the page access token using the graph explorer using the app,  this then works.  But once i've logged out it doesn't work and the page access token changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Documentation and found examples are not too bad and give some clarification on how to interact with FB via their API.

The only very confusing thing was how to get that mighty access_token and how to renew it when it expired without single user interaction.

Everything is pretty well described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ page except that you need read every single word and understand every single sentence to find out your answer. If you'll read through table of content and then paragraphs' headers you won't get a feeling that you are on the right way of searching for your key words.

Key information important for me was sitting under "Extending Page Access Tokens" title. The problem is that I don't want to extend token, I need something more permanent. The words which were finishing my puzzle were in the last paragraph of that section. And they were saying this:

> To get a longer-lived Page access token, exchange the User access
>   token for a long-lived one, as above, and then request the Page token.
>   The resulting Page access token **will not have any expiry time**.

After seeing that, I have generated permanent access token using FB Graph Tools, checked it with Graph debugger, added it to app settings and that was it.

**You can post to the Page without user interaction after getting that access token once.**

Happy Days...